# how does morphia skip deal with new records arriving during pagination?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I've read a lot about using skip with paging (and the related performance issues).  For my application, the performance issues are not a problem, however, it's not clear to me what happens with skip if new records arrive in between requesting pages.

For example, let's say I have 10 records, a user requests a page of 5 and we deliver them.  When the user is browsing the first page, another 5 records are inserted into the db, the user requests the next page of 5.  Assuming we're sorting on id or date, will the user now be returned the same 5 records (because, for the second page, skip skips the first 5 newly added records and returns the next 5, which are now the same records that were originally returned)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Both performance and correctness with added / removed entries is an issue.

For a good explanation see http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset (Markus Winand has been fighting offset for years ;-) ).
Keyset pagination is neither supported in MongoDB nor in Morphia from what I know, so you'll have to build it yourself. Make sure you're always working with something unique (like date and ID).

Other systems have implemented this feature natively, for example in Elasticsearch with [search after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-request-search-after.html).